# Flutter meterial icons not showing using IconData CodePoint

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following `Widget` with an Icon (`close_rounded`) that I wanted to show.

```
const ListTile(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
  trailing: Icon(
    IconData(0xf11b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), // <--- not renderable
    size: 40.0,
    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  ),
  title: Text(
    'The Enchanted Nightingale The Enchanted Nightingale',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
  subtitle: Text(
    '15 secs',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
  ),
);
```

The `Icon` that I want to show using `IconData(0xf11b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')`

The `IconData` I copied from [close_rounded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/close_rounded-constant.html) which is one of icon from [Icon_class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html). However it shows something like this:

[image]

I have also check `pubspecs.yaml` and `uses-material-design: true` is enabled by default

Comment: Why not just using `Icon`?

Comment: because I want rounded icon, it is not found in Icon list as what I see in my VS Code, I only got `Icon.close` but it's not rounded

Comment: I just run the Given code in Dart Pad. It's working fine. May be try pub-get or restart ide.

Comment: your code is working just fine in dartpad.dev

Comment: working in dartpad.dev doesn't meant anything. am I missing required package or what? Do you guys able to build in your own ide?